# Java PostgreSQL insertion throws unexpected error

Tags: java, postgresql

In my table I have a primary key character varying(64)[] column.

Following code:

```
Statement stmt = c.createStatement();
String sql =
        "INSERT INTO schema.table (integer_col, char_varying_col) VALUES (2, 'hi');";
stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
stmt.close();
```

Throws:

```
ERROR: malformed array literal: \"hi\"\n  Detail: Array value must start with \"{\" or dimension information.\n  Position: 82
```

But if I change the statement to

```
Statement stmt = c.createStatement();
String sql =
        "INSERT INTO schema.table (integer_col, char_varying_col) VALUES (2, '{hi}');";
stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
stmt.close();
```

Then it inserts `{hi}` to the table ..

Comment: You have an array column - is that not what you wanted?

Comment: Can you show the ddl for the table? despite its name `char_varying_col` seems to have an array type...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined your column type as array. So either change it to simple text column or change insert statement according to array structure.